# Proving the sum of null and time-like four-vectors

Tags: relativity

I need some advice on how I should go about proving this problem.

Problem: Show that the sum of null and timelike four-vectors, all forward-directed, is timelike unless all of the four-vectors are null.

I know $A=(a,ra)$ where $a$ represents the $ct^2$ part of the four-vector and $ra$ represents the space part ($x^2 - y^2 - z^2$) part of the vector. Letting $B=(b,rb)$, $b$ and $rb$ follow the same pattern as A.

So, if $a^2 - ra^2 > 0$ A is timelike, and
    if $b^2 - rb^2 = 0$ B is null.

Prove: $A + B > 0$

What I need help with specifically is how to prove the problem at hand. I don't really know how to "prove" anything. I've never taken a proofs class which I imagine would help here. Any advice on how to go about solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not going to give you the answer, but will try to guide your steps. This is mostly a homework problem, and you should try to do it. Try a couple things. But first note that your 2 r's have to be different. Right above you statement saying 'Prove ....> 0' the first r has to be such that 1-r  > 0, and the second one is 1-r = 0. So name them different. Then realize that summing the two vectors is summing their components, and let's call the result (c, hc). Do that and some algebra to get to to show that the expression $c^2 - h^2 c^2 > 0$ is true. That would be the proof.

By the way, your equations with inequalities are wrong, where you have r it should be $r^2$, also in mine in the paragraph above. Try it. It is not hard

Comment: Thank you so much! The r's are actually supposed to be square, and the a's and b's are supposed to be subscripts to denote the different r's. I think that is what you were referring when you said the r's are supposed to be squared and different r's. Anyway, thank you!! Starting to work it out now.

Comment: Post your answer when you get it. Subscripts would like  be $r_b$. Just an underline